# Area inside the circle $x^2+y^2=4$, under $y=x\sqrt{3}$ and above $y=1$

Tags: area, polar-coordinates

I have to find the area in the circle $x^{2}+y^{2}=4$ such that it's under the line $y=x\sqrt{3}$ and above $y=1$.

Since in polar coordinates $x=r\cos(t), y=r\sin(t)$, then if $y=1$:
$$r\sin(t)=1\Rightarrow r=\frac{1}{\sin(t)}$$
And due to the fact that the radius of the circle is 2, so the area should be given by
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\int_{1/sin(t)}^{2}rdrdt$$
but the integral above diverges. What's wrong?

Comment: You should not have $t$ starting at $0$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. how am I supposed to find out the initial value of $t$? I draw the region and I really have no idea.

Comment: The rightmost point in the region is at the intersection of the circle with the line $y=1$ which occurs at the point $(\sqrt 3,1)$.  The corresponding angle at this point is $\frac \pi 6$.

Comment: At intersection of circle $r = 2$ and line $r \sin t = 1$, $2 \sin t = 1 \implies t = \pi/6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Cartesian coordinate:

Intercept of $x^2+y^2=4$ and $y=1$ is $(\sqrt3,1)$.

Intercept of $y=x\sqrt 3$ and $y=1$ is $(\frac 1{\sqrt 3}, 1)$

Intercept of $x^2+y^2=4$ and $y=x\sqrt 3$ is $(1, \sqrt 3)$

$$A=\int^{\sqrt3}_1 \sqrt{4-x^2}dx+\int^1_{\frac 1{\sqrt 3}}x\sqrt 3 dx-1(\sqrt 3-\frac1{\sqrt3}=\frac {2\sqrt 3}3)$$

$$\int \sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx=\frac x2 \sqrt{a^2-x^2}+\frac {a^2}2\sin^{-1} (\frac xa)$$

$$\int x\sqrt 3 dx=\frac{\sqrt 3}2 x^2 $$

You finally get:

$$A=\frac 13(\pi-\sqrt 3)$$

Comment: @mvfs314 and sirous: `Seems the area is : $\frac{1}{3} \left(\pi -\sqrt{3}\right)$', as [@Rag wrote](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4888408) and as my answer confirms. Not $\frac{\sqrt 3}6+\frac{\pi}3-\frac 12$.

Comment: @AnneBauval, You are right. I corrected the error. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}A&=\iint_{1\le y\le\sqrt3\atop y/\sqrt3\le x\le\sqrt{4-y^2}}dxdy\\&=\int_1^{\sqrt3}\left(\sqrt{4-y^2}-\frac y{\sqrt3}\right)dy\\&=\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3}\sqrt{4-(2\sin t)^2}\;2\cos tdt-\left[\frac{y^2}{2\sqrt3}\right]_1^{\sqrt3}\\&=2\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3}(1+\cos(2t))dt-\frac1{\sqrt3}\\
&=2\left(\frac\pi6+0\right)-\frac1{\sqrt3}\\
&=\frac\pi3-\frac1{\sqrt3}.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

$y=\sqrt3 x\to\theta=\tfrac\pi 3$,$(\sqrt3,1)\to\theta=\tfrac\pi 6$.
The given region is spanned by $\tfrac\pi 6\leq\theta\leq\tfrac\pi 3$.

As you determined, the outer radius of the region is $r_1=2$, the inner radius is $r_2=\csc\theta$. Hence, by area formula
$$A=\int_{\tfrac\pi 6}^{\tfrac\pi 3}\tfrac12 \left(2^2-(\tfrac{1}{\sin\theta})^2\right)d\theta=\left.(2\theta+\tfrac12\cot\theta)\right\vert_{\tfrac\pi 6}^{\tfrac\pi 3}=\tfrac\pi 3-\tfrac1{\sqrt3}$$